# Knockoutjs observable array of objects binding selector by name

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array of observable objects called 
**FieldsAndValues** [image]

I'm binding the values of each object by their index using this

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DTO.FieldsAndValues()[0].Value, checkedValue: 'true'" class="separate" name="rdo">Yes

<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: DTO.FieldsAndValues()[0].Value, checkedValue: 'false'" class="separate" name="rdo">No
```

My question is, is there a way to bind the objects using the **LeaveFieldName** property as a selector and not their index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just the case of using foreach binding on that array, and not manually specifying the index of each node?

e.g.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: DTO.FieldsAndValues">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: LeaveField.LeaveFieldName, checkedValue: true" class="separate" name="rdo">Yes
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: LeaveField.LeaveFieldName, checkedValue: false" class="separate" name="rdo">No
    </div>
</div>
```

Plus, even if you bind it, your value will be either true / false, not the `IsRegularAndProbiSeparate` (etc.). That's what checkedValue binding is for. You even stringify boolean which isn't a good idea, should be just `checkedValue: true`

Alternatively you could use **with** binding (`with: LeaveField`) inside the array output and have access to all properties in each recurrence.